# Unable to use unlockAccount() in web3

Tags: web3js, blockchain, javascript

i am trying to unlock a account using unlockAccount() from personal module but i am getting an error

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const Personal = require("web3-eth-personal");
personal = new Personal(new Personal.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/############"))
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/#############"));
    try{
       acc = "0xd76d57a2F968587920D3ab2Db6BaC725a732263F"
       web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(acc)
        }

    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
```

i have even tried

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const Personal = require("web3-eth-personal");
personal = new Personal(new Personal.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/a9b1cf71e95a48ae8d9ca31790deae83"))
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/a9b1cf71e95a48ae8d9ca31790deae83"));
    try{
       acc = "0xd76d57a2F968587920D3ab2Db6BaC725a732263F"
       personal.unlockAccount(acc)
        }

    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
```

the error was

```
Error: Returned error: The method personal_unlockAccount does not exist/is not available
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/Users/vivek/programming/blockchain/sample/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

personal_unlockAccount is a Geth feature, and is not available for third party services like Infura.

When you run your own node like Geth, the node can secure your keys. Third party services can provide you with information about the blockchain, but they do not custody keys for you, nor should you want them to.

Comment: is there any way that i can send my ethers from one account to another account on test network

Answer (score 0):

As @AusIV correctly declared, you cannot use personal over third party services. You could do the following to send your funds:

```
tx_obj = {'from': from_address,'to': to_address, 'value': value, 'data': data, 'gas': estimated_gas, 'gasPrice': web3.eth.gas_price, 'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(from_address), 'chainId': web3.eth.chain_id}
sgnd_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx_obj, private_key_from_address)
transaction = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(sgnd_tx.rawTransaction)
```